# Botões com imagens em WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

Sou novo em WPF e estou querendo criar um botão, onde o conteúdo dele terá apenas uma imagem de fundo e nada mais. Não terá borda, cor de fundo ou texto, apenas uma imagem clicável.

Tentei fazer:

```
<Button>
    <StackPanel>
        <Image Source="images\icon_button_exit.png" />
    </StackPanel>
</Button>
```

Mas o resultado não foi agradável...

Eu quero algo algo assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

E então quando o usuário passasse o mouse por cima do botão ou clicasse, um efeito similar a esse aconteceria:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a melhor forma de fazer isso?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar isso em WPF, você vai precisar de 2 imagens, uma para o efeito padrão e outra para o efeito do Mouse Over.

Segue um link do Stackoverflow que possa ajudar a resolver esse problema:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657048/how-to-make-a-image-button-that-change-the-image-when-mouse-over-button-wpf

Comment: Esse link pode ser uma boa sugestão, mas sua resposta não terá validade se um dia o link deixar de funcionar. Além disso, é importante para a comunidade ter conteúdo aqui no site mesmo. Seria melhor incluir mais detalhes na sua resposta. Um resumo do conteúdo do link já ajudaria bastante! Saiba mais sobre o assunto neste item do nosso FAQ da Comunidade: [Queremos respostas que contenham somente links?](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/42/74)